# How to find line number of cursor in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I am reading a file in Python. After I read a bunch of lines, is there a convenient function that I can use to get the current line number in the file that the cursor is on?

I am trying to refrain from using a counter since I have multiple functions that read the same file and may move the cursor all over the place.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go line-by-line with [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html):

> ```
> import fileinput
> for line in fileinput.input(encoding="utf-8"):
>    process(line)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Something like [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)? There's is not really a "cursor" per say but the following will give you the current line number while reading a file line-by-line.

```
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    print i, line
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have multiple functions that read the same file so this method would not work. I am trying to refrain from using a global variable to keep track of the movement if I can.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to keep track of it separately, along with your file. You might wrap your file object to include a counter. Python itself only keeps track of how far along you are in terms of bytes, and has no way to move around based on line numbers.

Edit: I stand corrected. S.Lott's suggestion of `fileinput` is spot on.